# nginx redirect based on parameter id from uri

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect, location

need to redirect based on personId uri parameter.

Redirect https://server.com/de/prints/?personId=1 to https://anotherserver.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/the-result?statusId=1&personId=1

Need to do that for every personId value, so basically if request is: https://server.com/de/prints/?personId=2
redirect it to  https://anotherserver.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/the-result?statusId=1&personId=2

I've tried the following, but it's not working:

```
location ~* ^/de/prints? {
    if ($args ~* "personId=*") {
      rewrite ^.*$ https://anotherserver.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/the-result?statusId=1&personId=$1 redirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work using the following:

```
location ~ /de/prints/ {
         if ($args ~* "personId=(.*)") {
             return 302 https://anotherserver.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/the-result?statusId=1&personId=$1;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `$1` in your URL you need to capture the Id of the person in the original URL with parentheses (capturing group).

Something like `.*[&?]personId=([0-9]+)` instead of `^.*$`

Here is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/yms4Oi/1

Comment: Ok, so the if is not required anymore. Should be like the following:
location ~* ^/de/prints/?.*[&?]personId=([0-9]+) {
  rewrite https://anotherserver.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/the-result?statusId=1&personId=$1 redirect;
}
But it still doesn't work. Something is not right...